# PIDF XML Deserialization according to RFC 3863

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize activity into object type activities according to the RFC (converted XSD to C# class using the XSD in the RFC), but it seems like I'm encountering issues with the activity xml element, since it is containing a inner namespace in the attribute.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<presence xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf" entity="sip:anon@domain.invalid" xmlns:e="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:status:rpid" xmlns:dm="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:data-model" xmlns:ce="urn:cisco:params:xml:ns:pidf:rpid" xmlns:sc="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:servcaps">
  <dm:person>
    <status>
    <basic>open</basic>
    </status>
    <e:activities>
    </e:activities>
  </dm:person>
</presence>
```

I am deserializing this into a presence object, take the first (presence.Any[0]), and deserialize this into a person object, everything is fine so far. But then I want to take the activity element from person, and deserialize this:

```
person.Any.SingleOrDefault(x => x.LocalName == "activities")
```

But now the XML of that object looks like:

```
<e:activities xmlns:e="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:status:rpid">
    </e:activities>
```

And if I try to deserialize this into a activities object as of XSD in RFC3863, I'm ending with the following error message:

```
Message "<activities xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:status:rpid'> was not expected."
```

How do I deserialize XmlElements that contains a inner namespace like this??

UPDATE 23-11-17 (Elements which is empty):

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<presence xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf" xmlns:pp="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:person" xmlns:es="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:rpid:status:rpid-status" xmlns:ep="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:rpid:rpid-person" entity="sip:Alice@10.24.18.124">
    <pp:person>
        <status>
            <ep:activities>
                <ep:away/>
            </ep:activities>
        </status>
    </pp:person>
    <note>Unavailable</note>
    <tuple id="6001">
        <contact priority="1">sip:6001@10.24.18.124</contact>
        <status>
            <basic>closed</basic>
        </status>
    </tuple>
</presence>
```

Problem:

```
<ep:away xmlns:ep="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:rpid:rpid-person" />
```

Data Entities:

```
[XmlType(TypeName = "activities", Namespace = "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:rpid:rpid-person")]
public class Activities : activities
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:rpid:rpid-person")]
    public ItemsChoiceType State { get; set; }
}


/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:rpid", IncludeInSchema=false)]
public enum ItemsChoiceType {

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("##any:")]
    Item,

    /// <remarks/>
    appointment,

    /// <remarks/>
    away,

    /// <remarks/>
    breakfast,

    /// <remarks/>
    busy,

    /// <remarks/>
    dinner,

    /// <remarks/>
    holiday,

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("in-transit")]
    intransit,

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("looking-for-work")]
    lookingforwork,

    /// <remarks/>
    meal,

    /// <remarks/>
    meeting,

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("on-the-phone")]
    onthephone,

    /// <remarks/>
    other,

    /// <remarks/>
    performance,

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("permanent-absence")]
    permanentabsence,

    /// <remarks/>
    playing,

    /// <remarks/>
    presentation,

    /// <remarks/>
    shopping,

    /// <remarks/>
    sleeping,

    /// <remarks/>
    spectator,

    /// <remarks/>
    steering,

    /// <remarks/>
    travel,

    /// <remarks/>
    tv,

    /// <remarks/>
    unknown,

    /// <remarks/>
    vacation,

    /// <remarks/>
    working,

    /// <remarks/>
    worship,
}
```

Comment: Post the xml class you are trying to deserialize into.

Comment: Added here in pastebin as the source code is quite big: https://pastebin.com/Vj0XMK0d

Comment: I will look at a little later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare the namespaces correctly, especially the default namespaces.  See working code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string INPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string OUTPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Presence outPresence = new Presence()
            {
                person = new Person()
                {
                    status = new Status()
                    {
                        basic = "test"
                    },
                    activities = new Activities()
                    {
                    }
                }
            };
            XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlNameSpace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            xmlNameSpace.Add("dm", "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:data-model");
            xmlNameSpace.Add("e", "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:status:rpid");
            xmlNameSpace.Add("", "");

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Presence), "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf");

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;

            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(OUTPUT_FILENAME, settings);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, outPresence, xmlNameSpace);

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(INPUT_FILENAME);

            Presence presense = (Presence)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }

    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "presence")]
    public class Presence
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "person", Namespace = "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:data-model")]
        public Person person { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "person", Namespace = "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:data-model")]
    public class Person
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "status", Namespace = "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf")]
        public Status status { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "activities", Namespace = "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:status:rpid")]
        public Activities activities { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "status", Namespace = "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf")]
    public class Status
    {
        [XmlElement("basic")]
        public string basic { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "activities", Namespace = "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:status:rpid")]
    public class Activities
    {
    }
}
```

Updated code 11/23/17

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string INPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string OUTPUT_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Presence outPresence = new Presence()
            {
                person = new Person()
                {
                    status = new Status()
                    {
                        basic = "test",
                        activities = new Activities()
                        {
                        }
                    },
                }
            };
            XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlNameSpace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            xmlNameSpace.Add("pp", "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:person");
            xmlNameSpace.Add("ep", "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:rpid:rpid-person");
            xmlNameSpace.Add("", "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf");

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Presence), "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf");

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;

            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(OUTPUT_FILENAME, settings);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, outPresence, xmlNameSpace);

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(INPUT_FILENAME);

            Presence presense = (Presence)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }

    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "presence")]
    public class Presence
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "person", Namespace = "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:person")]
        public Person person { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "person", Namespace = "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:person")]
    public class Person
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "status", Namespace = "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf")]
        public Status status { get; set; }

    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "status", Namespace = "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf")]
    public class Status
    {
        [XmlElement("basic")]
        public string basic { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "activities", Namespace = "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:rpid:rpid-person")]
        public Activities activities { get; set; }

    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "activities", Namespace = "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:rpid:rpid-person")]
    public class Activities
    {
        [XmlElement("away")]
        public string away { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your simplified data schema would probably do the trick (and is even prettier than the origianl Xml entities. But, the Xml  classes posted, is from XSD based on different RFCs, and for that reason, I really want to find a solution, that will work against those entities, auto-generated based on the XSDs (i.e. the XSD in Flexisip project: https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/flexisip/tree/master/src/xml), which is based on RFC 4479 (common and datamodel namespaces), RFC 4480 (Rpid namespace) and RFC3863 (pidf namespace), some of them seems to have cross-refs.

Comment: Do you have a working example based on the entities combines from those XSDs? C# Entities  -> https://pastebin.com/HdF6FfvZ. XSDs used are following: https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/flexisip/blob/master/src/xml/rpid.xsd https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/flexisip/blob/master/src/xml/xml.xsd https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/flexisip/blob/master/src/xml/pidf%2Bxml.xsd https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/flexisip/blob/master/src/xml/data-model.xsd https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/flexisip/blob/master/src/xml/common-schema.xsd

Comment: Are you just de-serializing or also serializing?  The validation of an xml is done during serialization.  Deserializing you are just forced to use the provided xml.  So as long as you are able to read the xml there is no issue.  The only thing you want to make sure of during serialization that the type is correct (int, long, string, DateTime,....).  I don't like auto generated code because it is usually much more complicated than necessary and makes it hard to understand and maintain.  I like my pretty code.

Comment: I only need to deserialize an xml string into these objects (tho it would be neat to be able to serialize as well). Regarding the simplified entities, I agree with you that they are better, but in this case it is required to the XSDs created by the related RFCs. I'm not sure why they those that the status entity is a "Any" XmlAttribute object type in the XSD, could be since the status object of a person is optional not mandatory.

Comment: It is machine code that is designed to handle lots of different cases.  Manually generated code you don't need to add the optional parameters.

Comment: I have another occurrence, where the child of a xml element will not get deserialized (please look at the updated question). I do not get the <ep:away xmlns:ep="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:pidf:rpid:rpid-person" /> value in my State. Any suggestions to this one? I actually thought namespace wasn't necessary, as the parent (Activities) are within same namespace.

Comment: That's not generic enough. Then I had to create a property for each value of ItemsChoiceType enumeration.